# Spring mvc Jackson date remove time

Tags: date, spring-mvc, jackson

I have an incoming json `{"frm":"2014-12-02","to":"2018-03-03"}`. In my spring mvc app it is getting converted into the respective object.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class Lab {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date frm;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date to;
}
```

When I print the value of this class, I get result for "frm" as

```
Lab(frm=Tue Dec 02 05:30:00 IST 2014, to=Sat Mar 03 05:30:00 IST 2018)
```

However, I wanted the value like

```
Lab(frm=Tue Dec 02 00:00:00 IST 2014, to=Sat Mar 03 00:00:00 IST 2018)
```

While conversion from json to java "5:30" is automatically getting added which I don't want.
Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your backend is in IST but when the date is sent, it is in UTC.  When `2014-12-02` is entered on the front end, it's translated to the time in `ms` since epoch when processed by jackson.  One solution is to add the timezone to the `JsonFormat` like:

`@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", timezone = "IST")`

This link has more info:
http://www.saturnringstation.com/2017/01/07/learning-deserialization-of-date-with-timezone-jackson-mybatis-and-mysql-why-does-it-always-one-day-early/